# Horizontal scalability in Cloud Spanner

Tags: scalability, google-cloud-spanner

Cloud Spanner claims that its infinitely scalable database solution. How Cloud Spanner actually implements horizontal scalability under the hood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d recommend you take a look at these three videos in the Spanner: Database Unlimited Series.

1. [What is Cloud Spanner?](https://youtu.be/bUSU1e9j8wc)
2. [Delivering high availability at scale](https://youtu.be/8-R6k2u6sgk)
3. [Delivering strong consistency at scale](https://youtu.be/sOtlaH-QlxM)

There’s also a good [visual explainer](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/what-cloud-spanner) on the Google Cloud blog. And the [white paper](https://research.google/pubs/pub39966/) from 2012.